# php Form posting fails during insert using for loop

Tags: php

After I post the form, I am running a for loop to insert values in the table.

In the below example  it will stop executing name_4.

How to solve this  ?

```
<input type ="text" name="name_0" value="" >
<input type ="text" name="name_1" value="" >
<input type ="text" name="name_3" value="" >
<input type ="text" name="name_4" value="" >

array
(
[name_0] => sometext1
[name_1] => sometext2
[name_3] => sometext3                   
 [name_4] => sometext4           
)        
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++)
{
    "insert into table(field) values('".$_REQUEST['name_'$i]."')"; 

}
```

Comment: It's `$_REQUEST['name_'.$i]`

Comment: see, you had defined `name_4` that the for loop won't get to `4`

Comment: Yes ,it wont execute but how do you overcome that ? any turnaround solution?

Comment: Because you did not define each number, I suggest you use "foreach" instead of a simple for loop.

Comment: change the number in your for loop!!

Comment: Use arrays for the post values: `name="name[0]"`, then your post data will be an array, and you can check the length: `count($_POST['name'])`, which you use as the upper end for your `for...` loop. Also, this code is wide open to SQL injection: you should be using a token or manually sanitizing that value before you stick it in the database.

Comment: How about `$_REQUEST['name_{$i}']`

Answer (score 2):

Since your code does not work anyway, I am going to write a proposal on how to do this, you can take it or leave it. First, change your inputs like this:

```
<input type ="text" name="name[0]" value="" />
<input type ="text" name="name[1]" value="" />
<input type ="text" name="name[3]" value="" />
<input type ="text" name="name[4]" value="" />
```

Notice how I changed `name_0` to `name[0]`, etc. Then, your php can work like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $name=>$value) {
  //$name will now contain "0","1","3","4"
  //$value will contain each value
  echo "insert into table(field) values('".$value."')"; 
}
```

This example contains no input sanitation whatsoever, it is just an example on which you can continue to work, but if you ask me, it is better and cleaner than what you provided. You do not have to worry about skipped values, missing something, etc.